# Conditional clause in PROLOG doesn't work

Tags: list, prolog

I created a clause for conditional sentences but when I will depure the program using the trace command appear the fail message:

[fail message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XGnI.png)

I wanna check if a sub-list are in my list, if yes, I will increment my counter to annulate the decrement that happens after, otherwise, I will add the sub-list in my list.

My code:

```
if(condition,then,else) :- condition, !, then.
if(_,_,else) :- else.

createBombs(B,Q) :-
    Li = [],
    C is Q,
    repeat,
    random(1,10,X),
    random(1,10,Y),
    print(C),
    if(member([X,Y],B),C is C +1,insert([X,Y],Li,B)),
    C is C -1,
    C >= 0.

insert(X,L,[X|L]).
```

It's my first code in Prolog, so I'm sorry if was a very stupid error.

Comment: there are so many misconceptions... please peek a tutorial first

Comment: but my if clause are right? I'm researching about the other commands yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, you can try correcting your `if/3` like this:

```
if(Condition, Then, _Else) :- Condition, !, Then.
if(_, _, Else) :- Else.
```

With this definition, I get:

```
?- if(between(1,3,2), format("foo\n"), format("bar\n")).
foo
true.

?- if(between(1,3,4), format("foo\n"), format("bar\n")).
bar
true.
```

The `repeat` however later in your code is completely out of place and should be removed. There are too many other issues (as noted in the comments) that it is difficult for me to understand what you are trying to do.